# Symfony2 + FOSUserBundle -> User and Company extends Profile

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I actually build a website with Symfony2 + FOSUserBundle ..

I have multiple models with inheritance :

Profile has address,phone,zipcode etc..
Profile can create articles, videos and more ..

Company extends Profile and belongs to User

User extends Profile AND BaseUser ??

I want my User entity to extends Profile and FOS\BaseUser

How I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: PHP does not support multiple inheritance of course.  You best bet is composition i.e. a one-to-one-relation between User and Profile and another between Company and Profile.

Comment: You just need to  use FOS\BaseUser Bundle and no need to use your own bundle. In FOS bundle you can customize everything as you want.So why actually you made the seprate user bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding what you are saying, you have a User, Profile and Company object.

Your Company extends your profile, and you want user to extend both profile and user.

I think your object model might be a little skewed.  A User has a Profile, so it should contain the profile.

If your treating your user as having a Company then it would contain that as well.

$user->getProfile()->getAddress();

$user->getCompany()->getAddress();

Also if you at some point may have multiple addresses, phone #s etc. It would be wise to split this out further.

User has a Profile which has one or more addresses.